# FLASK-ADDING DATETIME CALCULATION INTO DATABASE

Tags: datetime, flask, sqlalchemy

I m trying to perform a little calculation and Logic on date.time with Flask application.
1.) the application will calculate the difference between issue date and expiry date called "remaining days" , The application will check if remaining days is less than 365 days and trigger a function

I attempted the first logic to manipulate the data and submit to database

`@bp.route('/cerpacs/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_cerpac():
"""
Add a an  Cerpac/ expartriates  to the database
"""
check_admin()
add_cerpac = True

```
form =CerpacForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    cerpac = Cerpac(cerpac_serial_no=form.cerpac_serial_no.data, 
    cerpac_issue_date= form.cerpac_issue_date.data, 
    cerpac_exp_date=form.cerpac_exp_date.data,
    employee =form.employee.data, )
    form.cerpac_issue_date.data = cerpac.cerpac_issue_date
    form.cerpac_exp_date.data = cerpac.cerpac_exp_date
    if request.method == 'POST':
       todays_date = datetime.now()
       t = cerpac.cerpac_issue_date 
       t1 = cerpac.cerpac_exp_date
       remaining_days = t1 - t
       print(remaining_days)  - good prints my result!
       remaining_days = cerpac.remaining_days ----not adding to database
                             
    try:
        add cerpac to the database
        db.session.add(cerpac)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have successfully added a Cerpac.' )`
```

`
my model:

```
class Cerpac(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cerpacs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    cerpac_issue_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    cerpac_exp_date=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    remaining_days = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    cerpac_serial_no = db.Column(db.String(60))
    cerpac_upload = db.Column(db.String(20), default='cerpac.jpg')
    renew_status = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    process_status = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    renewcerpac_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('renewcerpacs.id'))
    employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employees.id'))
            
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Cerpac {}>'.format(self.name) model:
```

I want to add this to database and eventually write a function like this:
I had a mistake also in the code because I had error issue_date not defined. How do I define issue_date as a date.time variable?

```
def  remaining_days(issue_date, expired_date):
issue_date = datetime(issue_date)
days_to_go = expired - issue
if days_to_go == 365:
    renew_status== True
    print("time to renew")
print("We are Ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this to something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Cerpac(db.Model):
    ...
    cerpac_exp_date=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    ...

    @property
    def remaining_days(self):
        return (self.cerpac_exp_date - self.cerpac_issue_date).days

    @property
    def days_to_expiry(self):
        return (self.cerpac_exp_date - datetime.now()).days
```

Then, `days_to_expiry` and `remaining_days` become properties calculated when you query, and update automatically when they renew their cards.

Comment: Thanks I hope to read up @property setter and Getter. this has not given me the logic to set renewal for my card. though I can see you have the logic to determine the days remaining. I also want renew at say when expiry_date is less,than 11 months for exmple

Comment: Please detail how you want to "set renewal for my card".  You should have a cron job testing all the cards, then renewing those that have `auto-renew` set to True?

Comment: The above suggestion gives error:                                                                       
   return (self.cerpac_exp_date - self.cerpac_issue_date).days
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'the 2. The renewal card will auto renew  when the remaining _days is less than or equal 11 months

Comment: So `cerpac_exp_date` = None.  You need to fix that.

Comment: I tried checking this on my model and forms I can't seem to find where the variable  was set to None. The renew card has not been updated as promised

Comment: I was able resolve the Nonetype  error by creating a new variable in my model and also in my views, but I need a better way to fix this when in production mode